# How to decorate statement

Tags: python

I have a class named Operators, and this class has a bath of functions. I want to test the executed time for each function. So the code is looks like below.

```
Class Operators(object):
    def A(self):
       """do something"""
    def B(self):
       """do something"""

Class EvaluateWrap(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.op = Operator()
   def Evaluate(self):
      def _Decorator(f):
          functool.wrap(f)
          def Wrap(*args, **kwargs):
              # time_start
              f(*args, **kwargs)
              # time end, elapsed
          return Wrap
      return _Decorator

   def Run(self):
      @self.Evaluate()
      op.A()
      @self.Evaluate()
      op.B()
```

First of all, use self.Evaluate doesn't work, besides I find decorator only uses for class and function, so what should I do? many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use decorators inside a class on one (or more) of the member methods, i don't think it is reasonable. as a `class`  is a tidy container.

use decorator on one function, and then can be used to module-level methods or class methods.

for example,
@timeit decorator allows you to measure the execution times of dedicated methods  by just adding the @timeit decorator in in front of the method call.

```
import time

def timeit(method):

    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        print '%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \
              (method.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
        return result

    return timed

class Foo(object):

    @timeit
    def foo(self, a=2, b=3):
        time.sleep(0.2)

@timeit
def f1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'f1'



f1()
Foo().foo()

output:
f1
'f1' ((), {}) 1.01 sec
'foo' ((<__main__.Foo object at 0x103b849d0>,), {}) 0.20 sec
```

Comment: cool, but the methods which I want to measure all are interfaces, I can't add decorator on them. what I can do is only in EvaluateWrap class.

Comment: It is easy to turn statements into functions.  In your case you can define `def _run_A(self): self.op.A()` and def_run_B(self): self.op.B()` and call them from `Run`.  If your decorator needs state (e.g., because you are accumulating time across many calls), then make a separate `Timer` class with `timeit` as the call method using `def __call__(self, method): ...`.  You can even track per-object times for each method using `def timed(obj, *args, **kw)` accumulating times for each obj independently within the `timed` function.